# NSCollectionView with Dynamic Width Items Using Auto Layout

Tags: cocoa, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem, nscollectionviewflowlayout

I'm building an `NSCollectionView` that scrolls horizontally with items that look something like this:

[image: The Goal]

I have my `NSCollectionView` item defined in a .xib with auto layout constraints. The width of the item is defined by the width of the label plus the width of the count label (and its surrounding pill). All this is encapsulated by an `NSView` called "Box."

[image]

Here are the constraints for Box:

[image]

I have my datasource hooked up and everything seems fine except I can't get the width of the item to change based on the sizes of the views inside it.

From what I've read, I can't rely solely on auto layout to define the size here (I hope I'm wrong about that) much like I would with a dynamic height in an `NSTableView`. So I'm trying to calculate the size with the `sizeForItemAt` delegate method from `NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSSize {
  let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "PhaseItem"), for: indexPath) as! PhaseItem
    
  return item.box.fittingSize
}
```

When I print the `fittingSize` to the console, it looks right. But I'm getting a `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` crash related to the size of Box (it has a subclass of `RoundedWrap`):

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033c3890 H:|-(11)-[NSTextField:0x7ff6abf6e9f0]   (active, names: '|':Avid.RoundedWrap:0x7ff6abf74840 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033c6300 H:[NSTextField:0x7ff6abf6e9f0]-(7)-[Avid.BadgeView:0x7ff6abf6f120]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033c5400 H:[Avid.BadgeView:0x7ff6abf6f120]-(9)-|   (active, names: '|':Avid.RoundedWrap:0x7ff6abf74840 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033c39d0 H:|-(8)-[NSTextField:0x7ff6abf6f360]   (active, names: '|':Avid.BadgeView:0x7ff6abf6f120 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033c2760 H:[NSTextField:0x7ff6abf6f360]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':Avid.BadgeView:0x7ff6abf6f120 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033c3a20 H:|-(0)-[Avid.RoundedWrap:0x7ff6abf74840]   (active, names: '|':NSView:0x7ff6abf74a80 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033c3b60 H:[Avid.RoundedWrap:0x7ff6abf74840]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':NSView:0x7ff6abf74a80 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000033140f0 h=--& v=--& NSView:0x7ff6abf74a80.width == 0   (active)>"
```

The crash goes away if I remove the constraint that pins the trailing edge of the Box to the containing view, but then my `NSCollectionView` items don't appear at all.

Is there an easier way to do all this? How can I use auto layout to set the dynamic width of my `NSCollectionViewItem`s?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was on the right track. I just needed to add:

```
item.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
```

Like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
  ///...
  item.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
  return item
}
```

In order for the item size to be accurate.